# Select with subquery avoid running more than once?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like this

```
Select 
     Col_A
    ,Col_B
    ,Col_C
    ,CASE 
        WHEN (SELECT ...{a very complicated query}...) IS NOT NULL THEN 1
        ELSE 0
     END CASE AS Col_D
FROM
    MyTable
```

The subquery that produces Col_D returns an integer when it is not null.

I need to show the BIT that Col_D is, but I also need to show the INT that it returns. Normally, I would just rewrite the subquery and call it Col_E, but given it's complexity, I don't really want to run it twice. Ideally, I would have:

```
Select
     Col_A
    ,Col_B
    ,Col_C
    ,(SELECT ...{a very complicated query}...) AS Col_E
    ,CASE 
        WHEN Col_E IS NOT NULL THEN 1
        ELSE 0
     END CASE AS Col_D
FROM
    MyTable
```

Do I have any options? (MS SQL 2008)

EDIT:
Sorry - I should have mentioned that the complicated query includes a where clause based on my columns i.e.

```
SELECT ...{a very complicated query}... WHERE X = Col_A AND Y = Col_B
```

Comment: I think to get an answer to this you're going to need to provide more information about what `(a very complicated query)` is and how it relates to the other columns in your query. Can you create a temporary table with those results and then `JOIN` to that instead os using a `SELECT`, and then run your `CASE` against the `JOINED` row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if the results of your query are only a single value or null, you could use:

```
Select 
     Col_A
    ,Col_B
    ,Col_C
    ,CASE 
        WHEN t.whatevercol IS NOT NULL THEN 1
        ELSE 0
     END CASE AS Col_D,
    t.whatevercol
FROM
    MyTable, (SELECT ...{a very complicated query}...) t
```

Do be careful as this could result in a cartesian product though if there are potential multiple returns.  If there are fields you can join on, that might be a better approach (and since you're checking for NULL, you may need an OUTER JOIN).

Answer (score 2):

You can nest the query that returns `Col_E` in another `SELECT`, and add `Col_D` on top of it, like this:

```
SELECT 
     Col_A
    ,Col_B
    ,Col_C
    ,Col_E
    , CASE 
        WHEN Col_E IS NOT NULL THEN 1
        ELSE 0
     END CASE AS Col_D
FROM (
    Select
         Col_A
        ,Col_B
        ,Col_C
        ,(SELECT ...{a very complicated query}...) AS Col_E
    FROM
        MyTable
) X
```

This way you would not need to copy the query, because its result would be available to the outer `SELECT`.

Comment: +1 . . . This solution works in the more general case that "a very complicated query" is a correlated subquery.